# Comparing arithmetic functions.

Tags: number-theory

Can one help in comparing the positive integer $d$ with
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} \sum_{j\mid i}\mu\left(\frac{i}{j}\right)d^j,$$
for various values of the positive integer $n$, and $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function.

(At least for small values of $d$ and $n$). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *comparing* an integer to a sum, but presumably you can calculate the sum for various small values of $n$ to get some idea of what is happening. Did you try that?

Comment: I said for various values of $n$, so we are speaking about an integer for each value of $n$.  I thinked about writing a program (I thinked about GAP) which do this calculation for small $d$  and $n$, but actually I did not (since I need to learn more about this).

Answer (score 1):

For prime powers $d$, the expression
$$
\frac{1}{i} \sum_{j\mid i}\mu\left(\frac{i}{j}\right)d^j
$$
counts the monic irreducible polynomials of degree $i$ over $\mathbb F_d$.

So the expression in the question is the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree at most $n$ over $\mathbb F_d$.

For fixed $n$, it is a polynomial in $d$ with the leading term $1/n\cdot d^n$.